# Transmit a Word file to a database or FTP at the click of a button?

Tags: vba, ftp, ms-word

I would like to be able to send the contents of a merged word document to a database, either on a button click on the menu bar, or when closed (if saved).

I've found some working code but have a problem trying to modify it (VBA noob)

```
'Written: June 11, 2008
'Author:  Leith Ross

'Open the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetOpen _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetOpenA" _
       (ByVal sAgent As String, _
        ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
        ByVal sProxyName As String, _
        ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

'Connect to the network
 Private Declare Function InternetConnect _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetConnectA" _
       (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
        ByVal sServerName As String, _
        ByVal nServerPort As Integer, _
        ByVal sUsername As String, _
        ByVal sPassword As String, _
        ByVal lService As Long, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long, _
        ByVal lContext As Long) As Long

'Get a file using FTP
 Private Declare Function FtpGetFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpGetFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
        ByVal fFailIfExists As Boolean, _
        ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

'Send a file using FTP
 Private Declare Function FtpPutFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpPutFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszLocalFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

'Close the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     (ByVal hInet As Long) As Integer

Sub AutoClose()

  Dim INet As Long
  Dim INetConn As Long
  Dim hostFile As String
  Dim localFile As String
  Dim Password As String
  Dim RetVal As Long
  Dim ServerName As String
  Dim Success As Long
  Dim UserName As String

  Const ASCII_TRANSFER = 1
  Const BINARY_TRANSFER = 2


    ServerName = "ftp.myserver.com"
    UserName = "myusername"
    Password = "password"

    'This fails if I use localFile =  ActiveDocument.FullName 
    'but is OK if localFile is hardcoded

    localFile = "f:\My Documents\Test.Txt"
    hostFile = ActiveDocument.Name

    If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The document must be saved first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

      RetVal = False
      INet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1&, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0&)
        If INet > 0 Then
          INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, ServerName, 0&, UserName, Password, 1&, 0&, 0&)
            If INetConn > 0 Then
              Success = FtpPutFile(INetConn, localFile, hostFile, BINARY_TRANSFER, 0&)
              RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INetConn)
            End If
         RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INet)
        End If

      If Success <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Upload process completed")
      Else
        MsgBox "FTP File Error!"
      End If

End Sub
```

I want the localFile variable to be dynamic and reflect this current document, but it only works if hardcoded. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Aren't you trying to write the document to itself if you use the dynamic names proposed for localFile and hostFile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edited, now works to send a copy of the current word document to the ftp server.

```
'Written: June 11, 2008
'Author:  Original author Leith Ross
'Amended: Jun 25, 2010 Saul Galloway

'Open the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetOpen _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetOpenA" _
       (ByVal sAgent As String, _
        ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
        ByVal sProxyName As String, _
        ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

'Connect to the network
 Private Declare Function InternetConnect _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "InternetConnectA" _
       (ByVal hInternetSession As Long, _
        ByVal sServerName As String, _
        ByVal nServerPort As Integer, _
        ByVal sUsername As String, _
        ByVal sPassword As String, _
        ByVal lService As Long, _
        ByVal lFlags As Long, _
        ByVal lContext As Long) As Long

'Get a file using FTP
 Private Declare Function FtpGetFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpGetFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszNewFile As String, _
        ByVal fFailIfExists As Boolean, _
        ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

'Send a file using FTP
 Private Declare Function FtpPutFile _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     Alias "FtpPutFileA" _
       (ByVal hFtpSession As Long, _
        ByVal lpszLocalFile As String, _
        ByVal lpszRemoteFile As String, _
        ByVal dwFlags As Long, _
        ByVal dwContext As Long) As Boolean

'Close the Internet object
 Private Declare Function InternetCloseHandle _
   Lib "wininet.dll" _
     (ByVal hInet As Long) As Integer

Sub AutoClose()

  Dim INet As Long
  Dim INetConn As Long
  Dim hostFile As String
  Dim localFile As String
  Dim Password As String
  Dim RetVal As Long
  Dim ServerName As String
  Dim Success As Long
  Dim UserName As String
  Dim currentFileAndPath As String

  Const ASCII_TRANSFER = 1
  Const BINARY_TRANSFER = 2


    ServerName = "ftp.yourserver.com"
    UserName = "username"
    Password = "yourpassword"

    currentFileAndPath = ActiveDocument.FullName
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs ("C:\TempFile.doc")
    ActiveDocument.SaveAs (currentFileAndPath)

    localFile = "C:\TempFile.doc"
    hostFile = ActiveDocument.Name

    If Len(ActiveDocument.Path) = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The document must be saved first."
        Exit Sub
    End If

      RetVal = False
      INet = InternetOpen("MyFTP Control", 1&, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0&)
        If INet > 0 Then
          INetConn = InternetConnect(INet, ServerName, 0&, UserName, Password, 1&, 0&, 0&)
            If INetConn > 0 Then
              Success = FtpPutFile(INetConn, localFile, hostFile, BINARY_TRANSFER, 0&)
              RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INetConn)
            End If
         RetVal = InternetCloseHandle(INet)
        End If

      If Success <> 0 Then
        MsgBox ("Upload process completed")
      Else
        MsgBox "FTP File Error!"
      End If

End Sub
```